# Goncharov's Proof of the Probability having $k$ cycles of size $j$ in a random permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, proof-explanation, inclusion-exclusion

The following proof of Goncharov (page 13 of *Logarithmic Combinatorial Structures*, by Arratia, Barbour, and Tavare) proves that $$\mathbb{P}\left(C_{j}\left(n\right)=k\right)=\frac{j^{-k}}{k!}\sum_{l=0}^{\lfloor n/j \rfloor - k}\left(-1\right)^l \frac{j^{-l}}{l!},$$

where $C_{j}\left(n\right)$ is the number of cycles of length $i$ in a randomly chosen permutation in $S_n$.

[image]

> Question 1: Regarding the highlighted part, what is "the $r$-fold intersection of properties, summing over all sets of $r$ distinct properties"? **Since this example involves permutations and cycles, is there a more natural way to describe $S_r$?**

> Question 2: "For the other case, some two distinct properties have some element in common, so no permutation can have both of these properties, and the $r$-fold intersection is empty." **Why can't a permutation have both of these properties?**

Comment: In the problem statement, should $i$ be $j$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider  distinct cycles $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_r$ in $I$. The probability of the $r$-fold intersection of these $r$ distinct properties is $P(G_{\alpha_1} \cap G_{\alpha_2} \cap \cdots \cap G_{\alpha_r})$. They would like to sum these probabilities for all $\binom{|I|}{r}$ sets of $r$ distinct properties.

---

Suppose $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are distinct but share an element, say $1$. A permutation $\pi$ cannot contain both cycles $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ because the element $1$ can only appear in exactly one cycle of $\pi$, i.e. $\pi$ has a [decomposition of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ into disjoint cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation).